# How to compare this {% if v.dateOfBirth == '<null>' %} using python in html?

Tags: python, html, django, tags, django-templates

I am using python in my html code. I would like to compare whether the python variable v.dateOfBirth equals the string `'<null>'` . The problem is that `<null>` is an html tag. How should I write `'<null>'` so I don't get any problems.

```html
{% if v.dateOfBirth == '<null>' %}
    <td> Not available </td>
{% else %}
    <td> {{v.dateOfBirth}} </td>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Which template library is this?

Comment: What template language are you using? Jinja2, Django, something else?

Comment: It is the Django-framework

Comment: `<null>` being a HTML tag shouldn't be a problem in the situation you're describing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it is looks exactly Django no?

Comment: And `v.dateOfBirth` is not a HTML tag, it is some other type of object that when `str()` is called on it will result in a HTML tag. You'll need to tell us what type of object is being passed into the template as well.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Jinja2 looks like that too.

Comment: What is `v` here? Is it a Django form, is it a query result?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: or just `if not v.dateOfBirth`. But this all depends on the object type.

Comment: dateOfBirth comes from my DB. It can be 'YES' or '<null>'

Comment: @user2935750: So it is a field in your model? What does the model look like? Please add that to your question.

Comment: You should consider the possibility that you have a poor model design. Having '<null>' strings just doesn't sound right. If values are coming from 3rd party (API?) you should rewrite it to `None` in an overloaded save method.

Comment: It also looks a little bit like a job for BooleanField: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield

Answer (score 0):

You should not get of problems, becouse in first django renders all cycles, ifs, templatetags etc. and after then create html. If this example not like to you, you can determine method in you model:

```
# models.py
class YouModel(models.Model):
    dateOfBirth = models.DateField(...)

    def is_null(self):
        return self.dateOfBirth == '<null>'

# template.html
{% if v.is_null %}
    # do something
{% else %}
    # do something else
{% endif %}
```